# Replacing last value in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

So, I have a tuple like this:

```
a=[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

and I want to replace last value of each tuple with 100. So I can do:

```
b=[(t[0],t[1],) + (100,) for t in a]
```

That gives me this:

```
[(1, 2, 100), (4, 5, 100), (7, 8, 100)].
```

What's the shortcut? These tuples, in real, have 50 elements in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use tuple slicing:

```
[t[:-1] + (100,) for t in a]
```

There is no need to build a completely new tuple from individual elements here.

Comment: Although, algorithmically, `tuple(chain(islice(t,0,len(t)-1),(100,)))` is a little nicer ... In practice this is likely to be significantly faster I would think.  (+1)

Comment: @mgilson: for shorter tuples, the tuple slice is going to be *much* faster still than the `islice()` as Python will reuse cached tuple objects; no memory allocation, baby!